# Making borders between polygons disappear in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, borders

I want to have no borders between the polygons of a layer WITHOUT dissolving it. If I set the border color to the same as the fill colour there shouldn't be any borders visible, right? I also tried to set the border width to 0, however, the result looks like this:[image]

you can hardly see the lines but there must be a way to get rid of them like in ArcGIS?

Comment: What about setting the **Outline style** to `No Pen`?

Comment: That leaves an even thicker white space between the polygons :(

Comment: What lines? could you may be ring an example of the line you see using a graphics program?

Comment: They are between all the countries, but you can hardly see them they are very very thin

Comment: I think setting the outline colour to the same fill colour is probably the best option.

Comment: that's exactly what I did here but the lines are still visible.

Comment: Perhaps a bug in QGIS 2.14.4. Could you try another QGIS version such as 2.16 and test it again?

Comment: I will try another version. But I also just noticed, it doesn't happen all the time but is somehow linked to rule-based style. When I imported the same shapefile with again using a simple symbol there were no lines. Because I need the rule-based style to highlight other parts of the map I used a quick and dirty solution: using the same layer as a mask with a simple symbol

Comment: Works fine in QGIS 2.14.5. Tried on simple, categorized and rule-based with no pen border style and also border with same color as fill.

Comment: on 2.17 (un-released) and there is no issue changing the polygon fill and outline. try exporting from postgis to a shape/mapinfo file to see if it is a bug with postgis rendering?